# very strange behavior in writing to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have very strange behavior.
For example,

```
with open("f","w") as fp:
fp.write(s) # s is string
```

If I write a lot of data then in the beginning of file I see garbage.

The same thing in the binary file.

If I change the mode from w or wb to a or ab then it's ok.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The `w` flag means "open for writing and truncate the file to zero length. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file."; you'd probably want to open the file with the `a` flag which means "open the file for appending".

P.S. I can not write a comment because I do not have enough reputation.